# Azure Devops Pipeline dynamic created stages to run in order/sequence rather parallel

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am currently working on azure pipeline with multiple stages created dynamically based on the input parameter(s), and want to run the **stage2_stg_x** in sequence rather than parallel(currently it runs in parallel). I couldn't found any possible solution to get that achieved.

Could someone suggest here.

[image]

main pipeline : test.yml

```
trigger: none

pool:
  name: 'linuxagent'

parameters:
- name: appComponents
  displayName: YAML list of Components to Build and Deploy
  type: object
  default:
    - stg_a
    - stg_b
    - stg_c
    - stg_d
    - stg_e

stages: 

  - template: pipeline/stages/stage1.yml

  - ${{ each appComponents in parameters.appComponents }}:   
    - template: pipeline/stages/stage2.yml
      parameters:
        appComponents: ${{ appComponents }}
```

stage1.yml

```
stages:
  - stage: stage1
    dependsOn: []
    displayName: stage1
    jobs:
      - job:
        steps:
        - bash: |
            # Write your commands here
            
            echo "Hello world"
            echo "i am here"
```

stage2.yml

```
parameters:
  - name: appComponents
    displayName: "Component name"
    type: object

stages:
  - stage: stage2_${{ replace(parameters.appComponents, '-', '_') }}
    dependsOn: stage1
    displayName: stage2 For  ${{ parameters.appComponents }}
    jobs:
      - job:
        steps:
        - bash: |
            # Write your commands here            
            echo "Hello world"
            echo "i am here"
```

Note : Here i have just using the basic echo for testing purpose. But my actual pipeline has different logic.

Comment: Hi PS83; I _guess_ you're defining those stage2 stages based on an [each loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#each-keyword)? Could you show your YAML, to confirm this?

Comment: Yes, thats correct. Stage2 is based on each loop and that is what i Want based on my requirement. updated the question with yaml(s)

Comment: People have put this question to MS, without getting any constructive answer: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/access-iterator-inside-each-loop/1192557

Answer (score 1):

Try removing "dependsOn" from all your stages.
I have a similar setup and the stages all just depend on the stage before them.